# Produce rolling view only for specific rows in Pandas based on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame that has information on times at which failure events happened for particular objects. Each row consists of the ID of the object, a starting time (this column is a full, properly-formatted Pandas Datetime series) for the record, a duration of that record (in hours), some sort of flag, and whether that flag corresponds to a failure. The flags more generally tell something about the operating conditions for that row.

I am interested in producing some sort of rolling window that will look back in the DataFrame for a period of 24 hours, and produce new columns that 1: tell us the total duration of non-failure related rows. Additionally, I would like to have a string that summarizes all the flags that are seen within that window. This action should not look outside of the ID group. However, I only need this information for rows that correspond to failures.

These rows only represent approximately a few hundred out of the several hundred thousand rows that I have, so I could in principle brute-force it. But I feel like there is a better way of achieving this.

To give you a better idea of what I'm hoping to achieve, here is code to produce a similar DataFrame:

```
np.random.seed(10)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['a']*5 + ['b']*5,
    'start': np.array(
        [np.datetime64('2017-06-01') + np.timedelta64(12,'h')*i for i in range(5)]*2
    ),
    'duration': np.random.choice([3,4,5,6], size=(10,)),
    'failed': [False,False,False,True,False,True,False,False,False,False],
    'flag': np.concatenate([
        np.random.choice(['1','2','3'], size=3), np.array(['8', '1', '8']),
        np.random.choice(['1','2','3'], size=4)
    ])
})
```

Which produces this:

```
   duration  failed flag id               start
0         4   False    1  a 2017-06-01 00:00:00
1         4   False    2  a 2017-06-01 12:00:00
2         3   False    2  a 2017-06-02 00:00:00
3         6    True    8  a 2017-06-02 12:00:00
4         3   False    1  a 2017-06-03 00:00:00
5         4    True    8  b 2017-06-01 00:00:00
6         6   False    3  b 2017-06-01 12:00:00
7         3   False    1  b 2017-06-02 00:00:00
8         4   False    2  b 2017-06-02 12:00:00
9         4   False    1  b 2017-06-03 00:00:00
```

My deisred output in this case would look like:

```
   duration  failed flag id               start flags  total_dur
0         4   False    1  a 2017-06-01 00:00:00  None          0
1         4   False    2  a 2017-06-01 12:00:00  None          0
2         3   False    2  a 2017-06-02 00:00:00  None          0
3         6    True    8  a 2017-06-02 12:00:00   2,2          7
4         3   False    1  a 2017-06-03 00:00:00  None          0
5         4    True    8  b 2017-06-01 00:00:00     1          3
6         6   False    3  b 2017-06-01 12:00:00  None          0
7         3   False    1  b 2017-06-02 00:00:00  None          0
8         4   False    2  b 2017-06-02 12:00:00  None          0
9         4   False    1  b 2017-06-03 00:00:00  None          0
```